# Can I use an sqlite database created for android in IOS

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I have an Android app I wrote that uses a sqllite database,(the app is used for the reservation) now I want to write the same app for iPhone and I want to use the same database I used in Android app. My question is can I use the same database in IOS.

If yes, then how can be used and where I place the sqllite database (I mean what folder)? and the users must be online to see the update in the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Can I use an sqlite database created for android in IOS?**

Yes, an SQLite database is a a file (or potentially 3 files if using Write-Ahead logging). It's simply a matter of copying the file(s).

Typically (i.e. if not specifying otherwise) an SQLite database is stored in data/data/your_package/database/the_database_name

- where your_package is as per the App and the_database_name is the file name (may or may not have an extension).

  - Note if the database uses Write-ahead logging then 2 other files may exist, these being the_database_name-wal and the_database_name-shm. If they exist and are not empty, they need to also be copied.

**However**,

> and the users must be online to see the update in the database ?

Is a completely different matter though. SQLite is not suited to a client/server situation, as you would have to write all the code to provide this functionality. See [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) may be an option if you don't mind Google's policies reqgarding information privacy. Otherwise you are likely then looking at something like MySQL/MariaDB.